# What to fill out for NY State & City on IT-2104 for single person?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, new-york

My daughter is starting a new full time job in NYC.  She lives in Brooklyn.  She owed NY State taxes.  How should she fill out the [IT-2104](http://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/wt/it2104_fill_in.pdf).  Should it just be single 0 exemptions?  Why would it be different than the Federal form?

Answer (score 2):

IT-2104 is the New York State and City equivalent of the Federal W4. She should fill it out by accurately answering the questions on the worksheet, similar to the process she used for the W4.

Zero may very well be the answer, but you are asking a specific question, and no one can answer without the details required on that form.